# How do you solve this binomial proof?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, combinatorial-proofs

If $k, m$ and $n$ are positive integers such that $n>m>k$, Prove that $$\binom{m}{0}\binom{n-m}{k}+\binom{m}{1}\binom{n-m}{k-1}+\dots+\binom{m}{k}\binom{n-m}{0}=\binom{n}{k}$$

I have re-written the statement using factorial notation and assume I must cancel out the $m$ to get to the RHS. However, I have not idea how to do this algebraically.

I also wrote it out in summation notation $$  \sum_{i = 0}^k \frac{m! }{i! (m-i)!} ×  \frac{(n-m)!}{(k-i)!(n -m-k + i)!} $$

but I don't know what to do with this information. Can someone guide me?

Comment: See also [Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Interesting. Is it a useful identity?

Comment: At least, it deserved its name for some reason ;) And a [quick search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=vandermonde+identity) may give a feel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Combinatorial proof

The number $n \choose k$ tells us in how many ways we can choose $k$ elements out of $n$ elements. Now split those $n$ elements into two parts with $m$ and $n-m$ elements. To choose $k$ elements out of the $n$ elements we can choose $l \in \{0, \ldots, k\}$ elements out of the part with $m$ elements and $k-l$ elements out of the part with $n-m$ elements. For a given $l$ this results in ${m \choose l}{n-m \choose k-l}$ ways. Then summing over the different possible values of $l$  we get the result
$$
\sum_{l=0}^{k} {m \choose l}{n-m \choose k-l} = {n \choose k}.
$$

#### Algebraic proof

We split a binomial power into two factors with powers $m$ and $n-m$ respectively:
$$
(x+1)^n
= (x+1)^m (x+1)^{n-m}
= \left( \sum_{l=0}^{m} {m \choose l} x^l \right) \left( \sum_{p=0}^{m} {n-m \choose p} x^p \right)
\\= \sum_{l=0}^{m} \sum_{p=0}^{m} {m \choose l} {n-m \choose p} x^{l+p}
%= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left( \sum_{l=0}^{m}  {m \choose l} {n-m \choose k-l} \right) x^{k}
.
$$
Now, $n \choose k$ is the coefficient for the $x^k$ term. This is found by only taking the terms where $p=k-l$:
$$
{n \choose k} x^k = \sum_{l=0}^{m} {m \choose l} {n-m \choose k-l} x^{k}.
$$

Comment: I actually understand the way you explained the combinatorial proof! Surprisingly since I normally have a hard time understanding. The Algebraic proof is very clever and clear as well. So my method was incorrect?

Comment: Your idea of just expanding the binomial coefficients into factorials might work. I just don't know how to continue.

Comment: can you explain why it is $\sum_{l=0}^{m} {m \choose l} {n-m \choose k-l} x^{k}.
$ and not $\\= \sum_{l=0}^{m} \sum_{k-l=0}^{m} {m \choose l} {n-m \choose k-l} x^{k}$

Comment: ie how does$ \sum_{l=0}^{m} \sum_{k-l=0}^{m} = \sum_{l=0}^{m}$

Comment: @user71207. What does $\sum_{k-l=0}^m$ mean?

Comment: Sum from $k-l = 0,1,2...m$

Comment: But $l$ is fixed by the outer (the first) sum, and $k$ is fixed by us wanting the $x^k$ term, so how can $k-l$ vary?

Comment: Well I guess it can't vary if both $l$ and $k$ are fixed. Why did you combine them both into a single sum from $l = 0$ then?

Comment: I extract the $x^k$ term from
$$\sum_{l=0}^{m} \sum_{p=0}^{m} {m \choose l} {n-m \choose p} x^{l+p}.$$
That term is created when $l+p=k,$ i.e. for $p=k-l.$

Comment: @user71207. I didn't combine the two sums into one sum. The outer sum was already there and is unchanged. The inner sum, however, was reduced to only one term, the term that gives $x^k$.

Comment: "The inner sum, however, was reduced to only one term, the term that gives $^$" Ok I think this is critical. However, I'm still not quite grasping it. If we say $\sum_{p=0}^{m}$ is "fixed" for the $x^k$ term, what is the significance of $ \sum_{k-l=0}^{m} $ then? It is still a sum as $m > k$ so how does it become reduced

Comment: Begin with considering $\sum_{q=0}^{N} c_q x^q$. What does the $x^k$ term look like?

Comment: the $x$ term is generated when $q = k$. Therefore $
\sum_{k=0}^{N} c_k x^k
$

Comment: But $\sum_{k=0}^{N} c_k x^k = c_0 x^0 + c_1 x^1 + \cdots + c_N x^N$ which consists of terms of several degrees, not only of degree $k$.

If I ask for the term of degree 2, would you then say that it is $\sum_{2=0}^{N} c_2 x^2$? If so, what does $\sum_{2=0}^{N}$ mean?

Comment: Ah yes, I am wrong. I didn't think that through sorry. Would it just be $
\sum_{q=k}^{k} c_k x^k
$? That would mean that the sum is redundant. I know there is only one term when $x^k$. So in the above proof, it would be $
\\= \sum_{l=0}^{m} \sum_{k-l=0}^{0} {m \choose l} {n-m \choose k-l} x^{k}
 = \sum_{l=0}^{m} \sum_{k=l}^{l} {m \choose l} {n-m \choose k-l} x^{k} = \sum_{l=0}^{m} {m \choose l} {n-m \choose k-l} x^{k}$, because as you said "But  is fixed by the outer (the first) sum, and  is fixed by us wanting the $^$ term, so how can − vary"

Comment: Now you seem to get it.

Comment: Okie Dokie thanks for making me think!